# Raycast stops detecting when origin is too close to object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just begun developing my first game, and I'm entirely new to this. I'm trying to figure out how to to detect when a player is looking at an item, so they can pick it up.

First, I'm using the `FPSController` from Unity's Standard Assets.

The code I have below works until the `FirstPersonController` gets too close to the object in question, the code stops working.

I spent 3 hours trying to figure this out and I've been banging my head against a wall

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public float range = 3;

    void Update()
    {

        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray( transform.position, transform.forward );

        // if user is looking at an facing the object  
        if( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit, range ) )
        {
            Debug.Log( "You can pick this up!" );
        }
            
    }

}
```

**Edit**

After some investigating, poking, and prodding, it appears as though raycasts fail detection only on the pieces of the object that intersect with the Character Controller radius

Comment: How close do you have to be?

Comment: you need to be colliding with the object for it to stop working

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do not use raycast on this occasion, you should use collision detection. To do this, you must add BoxCollider to your GameObject Item and activate IsTrigger.[image]

Then add the tag "Player" to your FPS Controller.

[image]

And lastly create a script with the void `OnTriggerEnter()` and add it to your item.

```cs
//Upon entering the collision area in which IsTrigger is activated
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player") //if the collided object contains the player tag
    {
        Debug.Log( "You can pick this up!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I only want the player to be able to pick up the object when they're looking at it and this seems to allow for pickup on collision regardless of where the player is looking

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out quickly after realizing the issue was centered around the `Character Controller` was interfering with the raycast.

solution was to add a layer to my `CharacterController` gameobject called player (I used layer 3) and then exclude that layer from the raycast

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = new Ray( transform.position, transform.forward );

if( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit, range, 3 ) )
{
     Debug.Log( "You can pick this up!" );
}
```